# Logical NOT operation not returning expected value in c?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

I am trying to switch between 0xAA and 0x55 with the use of logical operators.

I know that I can change from 0xAA to 0x55 using `c >> 1`, but I am asked to do this using logical operators, not bitwise operators so I have no idea if it counts to use the >> operator...

But I am a bit confused at using the NOT logic operation.

I was sure that if I say

```
unsigned char c = 0xAA;
unsigned char b = !c;
```

Then b would be 0x55. Instead I got an output of 0. Shouldn't it switch every individual bit to its opposite, giving me 0x55?

Thanks for help.

Comment: You are confusing "logical" not with "bitwise" not. Try the `~` operator for comparison.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I see that works too. Although I am a little troubled here because '~' is also a bitwise operator, not a logical one. Should I possibly just assume that I can use bitwise operators? Is there no way to do this with logical operators?

Comment: What you are asking about is exactly what the bitwise ~ operator is designed to do. The logical ! operator works differently because it only works on boolean values, either "true" or "false", not on individual bits.

Comment: Go back to your instructor and ask them exactly which operators you are and are not allowed to use.

Comment: @zwol looks like I am going to have to do just that zwol.

Comment: I always thought the term "logical operator" is potentially a tad confusing. After all, several bitwise operators are bitwise *logical* operators - doing basically the same logical operation, but per-bit instead of per-the-whole-value. Could you have got the question confused? (or could your instructor have slipped up in the wording?). You cannot get from `0xAA` to `0x55` using *only* logical operators, but there are a couple of ways using bitwise (per-bit logical) operators.

Comment: @Steve314, I disagree that there are "bitwise logical operators". There are "bitwise operators" and there are "logical operators". However, many operations set the zero flag of the CPU's flag register. That still doesn't make them bitwise _logical_ operators.

Comment: @PaulOgilve - in the terminology of the language standard, of course you're right, but most newbies aren't experts in the terminology of the language standard, and most experienced developers aren't restricted to the culture of one programming language. The terms "and", "or" and "not" were understood to refer to logical operations even in propositional logic and boolean algebra, before anyone cared about the terminology for describing operations in a programming language that didn't exist yet. That wasn't about bits or bytes - it was about abstract values independent of representation.

Comment: @PaulOgilve - BTW - the C standard describes an "abstract virtual machine", and to the best of my knowledge makes no reference to hardware implementation details such as the zero flag of the CPU. I can't even give you a definitive statement that all processors have such a flag (though every CPU I ever coded for certainly did). However, the zero flag is typically one bit in a register full of bits, and is typically `1` to indicate a zero result. In short, it certainly isn't the C expected result from `&&` or `||`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Instead I got an output of 0.

The [logical operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_logical) work with [boolean values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type): `true` and `false`.

The C language handles any scalar value that is not `0` as `true` and `0` as `false`.
The [Logical NOT operator (`!`)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_logical) turns any true-ish value (i.e. different than `0`) into `false` (i.e. `0`).

---

Assuming you can use arithmetic operators (addition, multiplication, division), you can compute each bit of the input number, change its value using the Logical NOT operator then assemble these bits back in to a number that is the Bitwise NOT of the input number.

For example, the last bit of `c` is `c % 2` and the number that remains if this bit is removed from the number and the other bits are shifted to fill its place is `c / 2` (or `c >> 1` as you already know.)

Answer (score 1):

As @Code-Apprentice stated, the ! is not the correct operator as you are doing a mathematical not instead of a logical not. HOWEVER, your question states that you want to use logical operators, therefore the ~ operator will not suffice since it is not a logical operator.  Think for a moment about what the difference is between logical and mathematical operations. Logical operations do not perform arithmetic, they operate on booleans. How would you then go about using the logical NOT, AND, OR, XOR, etc. to accomplish your task? You might even try doing this by hand with a pencil and paper first (HINT: convert hex values to binary first)

Comment: What do you mean by "Logical operations do not perform arithmetic."?

Comment: And what is "this" which you cannot do with NOT, AND, OR, XOR, etc?

Comment: Logical operators work with booleans. There are no logical operators that will give you 2 + 2 or 15 - 7. You can only approximate arithmetic through the results of boolean operations. That is why the ALU in the microprocessor has both a logic unit and an adder. The logic unit for boolean evaluation and the adder for arithmetic evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to switch between 0xAA and 0x55 with the use of logical operators.

That's a daunting task. Expressions that use logical operators evaluate to true/false. I wish you luck with the project.

Regarding

> Then b would be 0x55. Instead I got an output of 0. Shouldn't it switch every individual bit to its opposite, giving me 0x55?

That's not what the logical operator `!` does. It evaluates to `0` if its operand is non-zero and to `1` if its operand is `0`.

Comment: Expressions that use logical operators actually evaluate to 0 or 1, which is then interpreted as true/false. The 0/1 is actually the key to solving the OPs puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

If you really must do this using only `!` and not `~`, I have thought of a horrible hack.  Because this is homework, I am not going to show you the entire hack, just a piece of it:

```
static_assert(CHAR_BIT == 8, "What is this, a PDP-10?");

union {
  uint8_t val;
  struct {
    uint8_t b0 : 1;
    uint8_t b1 : 1;
    uint8_t b2 : 1;
    uint8_t b3 : 1;
    uint8_t b4 : 1;
    uint8_t b5 : 1;
    uint8_t b6 : 1;
    uint8_t b7 : 1;
  } bits;
} u;
```

I assure you that, with this variable declaration and a C compiler that is compliant with C99+errata, which most, but not all, are nowadays, it is possible to flip all of the individual bits in a byte using only the `=` and `!` operators.

Answer (score 0):

The first line:

```
c = 0xAA;
```

is seen as 'true' when the second line

```
b = !c;
```

is executed, And `not true` is false so `b` is set to `false` I.E. 0

A point to be noted:  bit wise operators are NOT the same as logical operators.  `!` is a logical operator

Comment: It is not the first line that is seen as true. It is the value that _will_ be seen as true when interpreted as a logical value.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie,  It looks like I poorly worded my answer,  For clarification: the line: `is seen as 'true' when the second line`  (where I was not clear) was referencing the contents of `c`  in the second line

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to switch between 0xAA and 0x55 with the use of logical operators.

This is impossible because logical operators do not work that way. Instead, you need to use bitwise operators.

As you say, `!` is the logical NOT operator. It takes a "true" value and returns "false" or a "false" value and returns "true". Note that it inverts the **entire value**, not individual bits. In C, `0` is considered "false" and any non-zero numerical value is considered as "true". So `!0xAA` evaluates to `0` becasue `0xAA` is "true" and `0` is "false".

Contrast this with the `~` which is the bitwise NOT operator. `~0xAA` will evaluate to `0x55` just as you expect because it inverts each individual bit.

Comment: It's not impossible. In fact, it's quite easily done. I could give away the answer, but if I were to just spoil the answer, the OP might miss an opportunity to learn more about logical operators. Also, the OP isn't asking about doing math with logicals, nor how to code it, he's asking how to flip between two discrete values. Very simple to do with only one specific logical operator required.